# How to reexport CLR c++ static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I have these files:

- foo.dll
- foo.lib
- foo.exp
- bar.il
- bar.netmodule

"foo" defines functions in its export directory.

I also have a Visual Studio 2010 C++ project which will create a managed "bar.dll"

I want to "bar" to statically link to "foo" and **reexport** all functions from "foo".

In the end I want **bar** to export the functions from **foo** and some additional code defined in **foo**.

Using code below does not work as it references **foo** instead of merging **bar** with **foo**.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/include:_foomethod@12")
```

How do I do that?

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0z8kac4(v=VS.100).aspx

CFF Explorer to verify export directory: http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k669k83h.aspx

See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/texblog/archive/2007/04/05/linking-native-c-into-c-applications.aspx

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe" /DLL /LTCG /CLRIMAGETYPE:IJW   /ASSEMBLYMODULE:bar.netmodule   /OUT:bar.dll foo.lib bar.netmodule

foo.netmodule : fatal error LNK1302: only support linking safe .netmodules; unable to link ijw/native .netmodule
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to merge foo into bar. It is possible to forward the exported symbol in bar back to foo, though, e.g. as kernel32 does for some functions in ntdll. If you just want to check the export library you can also use [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com) or `dumpbin /exports bar.dll` from a VS command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

Instead those files will be required:

- foo.obj
- bar.cpp
- bar.obj

The C++/CLI compiler cl.exe will be able to compile bar, reference unmanaged and managed worlds.

In a later step linker will be used to merge obj files into one mixed mode assembly containing:

- unmanaged exports from foo
- unmanaged exports from bar
- managed IL types from bar

Command used for linking obj files:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe" /DLL /LTCG /CLRIMAGETYPE:IJW     /OUT:bar.dll *.obj
```

Extra: One can rename exported function names after cpp to obj compilation in the export directory to their liking :)